# How to make a fabric with a solidify modifier doesn't pass through itself?

Tags: modeling, cloth-simulation

I've created a sail. I made a plane of right form, applied to it solidify modifier and cloth modifier . But when I added a wind, back surface of the fabric touches front surface and passes through it.

[image]

How to fix this? 
If I turn on self collision - fabric swells, like a pillow.

Comment: you shouldn't apply the solidify , leave it the last  after the cloth

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't apply the solidify modifier , put it the last  here is an example setup :

- the mesh is subdivided before :
- the subsurf modifier is added to smooth the mesh after simulation then we add the solidify modifier.

[image]

Solid view :

[image]

Comment: @MaximVelichkin you are welcome !